# Harvesting Venus' atmosphere to Terraform Mars

Tags: mars, venus, terraforming

Since Mars has such a thin atmosphere, to terraform we would need massive amounts of Nitrogen. Would it make sense to import it from Venus?

Also since Venus' atmosphere is mostly CO<sub>2</sub>, and we can make O<sub>2</sub> from CO<sub>2</sub>, could we just import O<sub>2</sub> as well?  That might be faster than just creating O<sub>2</sub> using plants on Mars.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you believe there is an advantage to moving mass quantities of N2 from Venus to Mars versus "using just plants"? Especially considering we have basically no way at present to do either?

Comment: You might want to reconsider the biochemistry involved in using plants as a nitrogen source. And before you start transporting petatons of O2 across the solar system to Mars, you might want to see this chart: https://www.lpi.usra.edu/education/IYPT/Mars.pdf

Comment: "and we can make O2 from CO2," Would that be on Venus, or on Earth ? Because it seems on Earth there's too much CO2 too.

Comment: Beside "moving" an incredible amount of N2 (and CO2) from Venus to Mars: we would need to figure out how to get Mars caplable to keep the "new atmosphere".

Comment: Even if you move petatons of gases, Mars atmosphere will remain thin as explain in the question [Why is Mars' atmosphere so thin?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2310/23489)

Comment: Atmospheric escape would take place over millions of years. As far as terraforming for human inhabitation is concerned, the problem is just moving enough gases. (And that's quite enough of a problem.)

Comment: @CallMeTom I would guess we would have had a method to protect the atmosphere by then maybe similar as they proposed here https://phys.org/news/2017-03-nasa-magnetic-shield-mars-atmosphere.html

Comment: @Cornelisinspace My thought is that Venus gets a lot of solar energy so processing it around Venus before transport. Understand I would assume by this point we would have people there or at least a automated workforce able to do the job.

Comment: @TracyMcCormick Is any method allowed?

Comment: If one could create a 1m diameter portal deep in the venusian atmosphere which opens instantly onto Mars, how long would it take to establish a global atmosphere of 1bar on Mars?

Comment: The Venusian atmosphere is hot. Can we use the thermal energy to break down CO2 into carbon and oxygen? The SYNTHETIC allotropes of carbon can be graphite, diamond, carbon fiber, carbon nanomaterials, graphene and fullerenes. All could be used at the floating base on Venusian cloudtop? Essentially, the base would be made mainly of those carbons, plus imported aluminum and steel... I do not know how the whole process could function so it is not an answer to the original question.

Comment: @Kav Well my thought is at least believable science. ie I know we could move atmosphere between planets it may take time and energy. I read an article where they thought we could freeze the atmosphere. Once in orbit and stored they used something like a railgun to just launch the frozen gas at mars. No tanker needed.

Comment: @Innovine portals would be great but if we had that we might not even need to terraform mars at that point.

Comment: @TracyMcCormick Talking about frozen gas, can I take the idea of methane clathrate? Making use of the silicon dioxide in near-earth asteroid mining turns them into the host of the clathrate. The carbon dioxide (CO2) to be transported is trapped as the guest. Given extremely cold temperature in the space among the planets, pressure is needed to trap the CO2. Pressure by definition is force divided by area. If very small amount of CO2 in the scale of each molecule are trapped within the SiO2 clathrate, imagine those CO2 or even one molecule is "single-celled" inside the clathrate prison.

Comment: @TracyMcCormick The surface area inside the WHOLE clathrate can be very great so the whole can accommodate much CO2. Each "single-celled" CO2(s) experience(s) very small surface area. If force is exerted onto the whole, they can become liquid. The whole clathrate could be rail-gunned or sling shot from Venus orbit to Mars. Maybe an intermediate and additional sling shot near Earth is needed but I think you get my imaginations. On Mars the clathrate is carefully broken and package of CO2 is released. The whole clathrate could be re-used by slinging shot (or gunning) them back to Venus.

Comment: @TracyMcCormick What external force can be applied internally onto each cell is the tipping and crucial point of the imagination. Aim an electromagnetic radiation that is transparent (not absorbed) to both the glass and CO2 onto the cells, I imagine. No ultraviolet but sun shines all the time in space, so the whole clathrate needs a reflective blanket.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are easier ways to enhance Mars's atmospheric pressure, so no, don't use Venus materials. I calculated the energy required to lift a kg of nitrogen — or a kg of *anything*, for that matter — out of Venus's gravity well, and uphill through the sun's gravity well to Mars. Getting it away from Venus was a small part of the total, but that total was nearly *700 MegaJoules*, far more than chemically reacting 1 kg of *anything* could supply. Lugging stuff up the solar gravity well isn't easy!

But there are other ways. For example, there are many objects flying around in the solar system that contain huge amounts of volatiles, such as comets and some asteroids, and some of those are in orbits that are not as difficult to divert to Mars as lugging up from Venus. The savings in energy is greater than the energy needed to make N<sub>2</sub> from the NH<sub>3</sub> in, say, a comet.

That said, the amount of energy needed for this undertaking currently is far beyond what we can muster.

So no, for multiple reasons Venus shouldn't worry about somebody swiping its nitrogen!

Comment: My thoughts were if we were going to Terraform mars we might also want to terraform venus as well. These are mega-engineering projects and we would need to do something with Venus's atmosphere anyway.

Comment: The mass of CO2 in Venus's atmosphere is only about double the mass of CO2 locked up in carbonate rocks on Earth. With cooling of the atmosphere (not an easy task!) & the addition of Ca & Mg, we could precipitate the CO2 as limestone and dolomite. There *might* be enough Ca and Mg in Venus's crust to suffice, otherwise you need to bring in asteroids of the right type. Once you have the limestone and dolomite you use it to build pretentious government buildings, temples, and the like. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

No.  Moving N<sub>2</sub> or O<sub>2</sub> wouldn't make sense, because it would require moving about a quadrillion tons from one planet to another, while we've barely figured out how to move *one* ton up from one gravity well and down into another.

Once we can do that kind of engineering (pick a favorite technology from science fiction), we may have already become bored with terraforming.

Comment: Yea my thought is by the time we would want to do something like this we would have a lot of automation. Most likely if we wanted to terraform Mars we might also want to work on terraforming venus as well. I'm sure either project would take a lot of time and tech we haven't dreamed up except in Science Fiction.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to counter the naysayers. As long as we're dreaming of terraforming, this seems as good an idea as any.

First, I think there's a bit too much hand-waving along the lines of, "Well, once we could do that, we might as well... do... something... else??"
That begs the question, "What else?"
Two counter-suggestions, namely, using the elements in the Martian crust and using comets and asteroids each bear their own consideration.

Second, I think that there's a lot of heft to the idea of terraforming our solar system as a tandem problem, wherein any solution to the problems of one world may best be addressed by solving an inverse problem on another world. Mars is too cold and its atmosphere too thin. Venus is too warm and its atmosphere too thick.

Still, let's consider the alternatives in depth.

## Using the Martian Crust

Considering the elemental composition of Mars's crust is important, but NASA-sponsored research has suggested that there likely is not enough CO2 in Mars's ice caps and crust combined to pressurize the atmosphere for a greenhouse effect ([source](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/goddard/2018/mars-terraforming)).

Likewise, the [same paper cited in the comments](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/education/IYPT/Mars.pdf) doesn't indicate an abundance of nitrogen in the Martian crust that we could use for terraforming. Certainly any serious terraforming effort would require us to maximize the use of resources "on the ground", but if those resources aren't *in* the ground we have only one alternative: we will have to go *somewhere* else for some of our elemental needs to make Mars livable.

## Comets and Asteroids

This is likely to be an important piece of the puzzle, in no small part because it's feasible with today's technology. We know how to land spacecraft on comets and asteroids. Likewise, we could conceivably produce rockets with enough thrust to push comets and asteroids into an impact orbit with Mars.

Further, comets and asteroids have lots of desirable materials relevant to terraforming. Comets in particular are rich in water, CO2, methane, and ammonia, which finally gets us the nitrogen from the original question.

My chief question is what would be the actual effort required to wrangle enough comets and asteroids to get Mars's atmosphere up to an Earth-like atmospheric pressure?
There probably is enough raw material in the various asteroids and comets around the solar system to bring the Martian atmosphere up to one atmosphere. Indeed, the NASA paper cited above notes this.

> Another idea is to import volatiles by redirecting comets and asteroids to hit Mars. However, the team’s calculations reveal that many thousands would be required; again, not very practical.

So, the question is:
Is it *logistically* more prohibitive to put enough comet-chasing rockets into space and then turn them all to the purpose of redirecting the orbits of various small bodies than it would be to cart Venusian atmosphere to Mars?
I'm not sure, but let us at least consider the alternative.

## Back to Venus

One of the chief objections here is the cost of moving the atmosphere out of Venus's gravity well. Yet this is a central problem to most multi-planetary-scale engineering problems with lots of different proposed solutions. I would like to draw attention to the humble [skyhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_(structure)). Sure, it's not as flashy as a space fountain or space elevator, but it could be perfect for mining the Venusian atmosphere at scale.

On its descent into the atmosphere, one end of the skyhook could begin pumping material out.
On ascent, it could release it into a higher orbit where it could be gathered up and pressurized by an orbital tanker.
From there, it could be shipped off to Mars.

Granted, pressurizing a quadrillion tons of atmosphere and shipping it across the solar system is no mean feat.
And yes, a skyhook for Venus would be the single greatest engineering feat our species has yet accomplished.
Of course, so would putting thousands of comet-moving rockets into deep space.
The question is, what are the relative pros and cons of each approach?

The big advantage to Venus is that we begin the process of thinning Venus's atmosphere, which is an important terraforming project in its own right.
Another advantage I see over comet mining is that it's just one big problem to worry about, rather than thousands of small ones.

Comment: I find the exact science and numbers in your answer compelling! It is nothing at all like that guy in the blue suit waving his hands about.

Comment: Why not back to Earth for a skyhook, there's sufficient N2 here, and the skyhook has to be made on Earth too.

Comment: No need for a tanker once the material is in orbit. Just chuck it at the right angle and speed, and it will transfer to Mars. Use a railgun or something like SpinLaunch.

Comment: I hear you on the gif, @PcMan. Still, if I can't have a little fun while being an armchair scientist competing for fake internet points, why even bother? ;)

Comment: @Cornelis - My main reason for not harvesting from Earth is, well, I'd rather not inadvertently make our only home unlivable. We've already seen how subtle changes to atmospheric composition can affect climate.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens - solid point. The interplanetary tanker idea is probably the result of too many video games, too little physics study. :) I expect that once you've got the atmosphere into higher orbits, there are a variety of creative ways to transport it.

Comment: If the gas were dense and frequent enough, it would trace a dotted blue line across the sky from Venus to Mars.

Comment: If you want to source material to augment Mars' atmosphere (for terraforming), you would be best served mining one of the larges asteroids like Ceres or Vesta, or one of the very outer moons of Jupiter or Saturn, that require miniscule delta-v to send material on a Mars-crossing orbit. (arrival may be a bit violent)

Comment: remember the whole idea it to be able to terraform both planets. Solving Venus's problem can help fix Mars thin atmosphere.

Comment: Ah! ... if only we humans could make a wormhole link between Venus & Mars for the transfer of gases. Where are those friendly Aliens when you want them? :-(

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the gases from Venus for Mars but I would use them for rotating space stations between Earth and Venus. The distances wouldn't be that far and we don't need to worry about how we get massive amounts down to Mars.

A lot of you might dream of giant O'Neil cylinders, but the elephant in the room is the question: "From where comes the air for a structure that houses thousands of people?" Habitats between Earth and Venus can use a constant energy supply of solar panels and would be easy to reach from Earth and Moon
However the atmosphere of Venus could rather support a swarm of space habitats than a terraforming project on Mars.

When it comes to getting an atmosphere on mars I would, as already said in the discussion, use comets, because they are mostly made out of water, ammonia, CO<sub>2</sub>-ice, silica and other abundant alkaline metals. We could just throw them down on Mars. The ices would melt and release the gases and supply Mars with more water. We should know that here on earth most of our breathable air comes from algae, tang, plankton and bacteria in the oceans.

A stationary magnet on the L1-point, and the use of processed fluor-hydrocarbon gases out of Mars' crust also help to get a warm atmosphere.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question as to how to get atmosphere from Venus to Mars.  It also doesn't directly address why this might not be a practical option.

Comment: It does cause what I'm trying to say that, there are better ways of getting an atmosphere for Mars and a better usage for Venus' atmosphere. The awnser to the question is: We don't, the altenatives are better

Comment: @ERROR404 Welcome to Stack Exchange! What keeps SE sites working so well is a fairly strict adherence to the question and answer format. If the question were instead "What are ways to do X?" then this might be an answer. But when the question is so specific like this one, answers generally need to address the question as asked. This answer post really drifts off away from the question into several ideas, and doesn't really contain supporting links backing these up with science. For example, how would "stationary magnet on the L1-point" be able to "help to get a warm atmosphere"?

Answer (score -1):

Terraforming Mars would be a futile task as the atmosphere you would give it would corrode away without an electromagnetic sphere protecting the planet from solar winds.  And say you could undertake such a massive mission taking it from Venus would be extremely uneconomical as previously stated.  Also remember how volatile the winds on Venus can be.  Let's say that you can terraform Mars and want to do so although you know that whatever atmosphere you do make will simply disappear soon enough, the planet is dead, and humans of the distant future would condemn us for wasting resources on such a great magnitude.

Comment: Corrode away or erode away?

Comment: I would think that they would have solved this issue even before considering modifying the atmosphere for example this article from a few years ago. https://phys.org/news/2017-03-nasa-magnetic-shield-mars-atmosphere.html

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you could do that. It would take a fleet of autonomous nuclear thermal spaceplanes. Basically the spaceplanes dip into the atmosphere using externally heated turbines with ambient air as propellent while it sucks up and compresses ambient atmosphere. Use a portion of the atmosphere you just collected to leave the gravity well and trasport to a gigantic reservoir nearby. The reservoir goes near mars and then drops small iron cannisters to imlact the surface filled with pressuried venus atmosphere. The reservoir refills on iron cannisters from a mass driver up mount olympons. You would need hundreds of these reservoirs, 1000s of autonomous space planes, and decades of constant work. To be clear, these reservoirs make aircraft carriers look like a canoe.

To all who say the solar wind and mars magnetic field blah blah blah just be quiet. Its a non issue. A satellite inbetween mars and the sun of just a few tesla is more then adequate to shield mars. Sure the satellite will need maintenance but atmosphere bleed off happens over millions of years, and its not technologically difficult to make a satellite, just economically difficult.
The real question is why the hell would anyone want to terraform anything to begin with? Rotating space habitats can be made into a paradise. Screw getting close to good, choose great instead. Space habitats are objectively better in every way compared to a planet.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. Can you summarize your two paragraphs in a few sentences. My understanding is you are proposing to send the Venusian CO2 to Mars.

Comment: Yes its possible to transport venus' atmosphere to mars for terraforming. Its a very stupid idea to terraform anything since rotating space habitats are objectively better.

Comment: @VladimirSilver I think rotating space habitats are a good idea. But even with space habitats you would still need to fill them with n2 and o2 that needs to come from somewhere. Using Venus can help there too and further reduce the atmospheric pressure. But some people may prefer to live on planets instead.

Comment: As Ive said. Nuclear thermal spaceplanes dipping into the atmosphere of Venus. Titan would work as well. Much lower gravity but also much further away. A spaceplane would use quite a large chunk of its propellent leaving the gravity well of venus, which is why you use a large container to store the little bit left. Its a slow cumulative process. An alternative is to build gigangtic space mirrors aimed at a small portion of the atmosphere to cause thermal ionization and then a giant magnet to collect the ions. Spaceplanes are a far more direct approach.

Comment: Planets are not sustainable, nor are they ideal. They waste mass, waste energy, and harbor all sorts of nasty things like disease and natural disasters. Some people may prefer to live in a cardboard box but that doesnt mean their opinion should interefere with the construction of houses. Planets suck.